# TSQL "Array" - Update records based on a list and remember last used value

Tags: sql-server, arrays, t-sql

The title may be a bit confusing.....but I'm looking for a way to run a SQL Server job that updates records inserted into a table.

I have a list of people who would be assigned these records. We will be importing records daily and I want an idea on how to get TSQL to loop through these records and update them *but* want  way to remember the last person who was assigned so everyone has a similar amount of records.

Basically, I have a list of people

```
John

Steve

Jerry

Nick
```

So if there's 10 records imported everyone gets 2 records a piece, with the exception of John and Steve who get 3. On the next import, I want the update to remember that John and Steve received 3 records and to start with Jerry and use him as the starting position....so on and so forth...

Hopefully that was clear enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not much information in to go with here... but assuming your job has a JOB_ID and that this JOB_ID is a running sequence, then you can simple mod (modulo) the JOB_ID with the number of people you have. For Example in your case you have four people

John, Steve, Jerry, Nick.  Here John will be associated with 0, Steve will be associated with 1, Jerry 2 and Nick 3.

So, lets say Job_ID 1 comes in.

```
1 modulo 4 = 1 (Steve)
```

Similarly

```
2 modulo 4 = 2 (Jerry)
3 modulo 4 = 3 (Nick)
4 modulo 4 = 0 (John)
5 modulo 4 = 1 (Steve)
6 modulo 4 = 2 (Jerry)
....
....
....
....
Job_ID 359
359 modulo 4 = 3 (Nick)
```

And so on... This way you don't have to remember the last assigned person or anything like that. As long as the Job_ID's are fairly in sequence they will get properly assigned to the right person.

In T-SQL modulo operator is the following -

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279(v=sql.105).aspx